# scaling and positioning with tweenlite

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movieclip with the mesurements of a rectangle. When the application is launched the movieclip is being scaled before placed on the stage as following.

```
menu.width = 400;
menu.scaleY = menu.scaleX;
```

this is a smaller size than the original.
the position of the movieclip at this moment is in the middle on the x and top of the stage on the y.
when i click iti would like to do a tween with tweenlite wich scales it  to its original(bigger) width and height and position it in the center of the stage on x and y.

the problem is when i position it with tweenlite, it gets done according to its old scale and not according to its new(bigger) scale so the movieclip isnt placed in the exact center of the stage. 
Anyone know how i can resolve this?

I tried to compensate by adding a bigger number on the position so it gets positioned in the right way.

But when i click it again i would like it to rescale to its beginning scale and position so it would be very messy to compensate again. Is there any easier way to do this kind of tween?

I doubt that i'm being clear to what i want but i hope i am after all.

Answer (score 0):

The easy and way of tween position and scale is probably to add the menu to a container.
You would then on one hand tween the position of the container, and on the other apply the scale to the menu it self without having to recalculate the proportional position if the scale changes.

This way you can even control the registration point of the menu within the container. e.g. to always scale from the middle...

This can be done with a matrix as well if you want to avoid to stack objects, but honestly it can get really tricky whereas the container method is bullet-proof.

Comment: Ty for your response, i doesnt work thou, i add the menu to the container and then i add the container to the stage. After that i give the container a width of 800 and then i give the menu a width of 400 but when i run the application the menu still gets a width of 800 so it adapts the width of the container. Dunno why since i assign the menu width after the container.